# A question about complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> Let $z_0\in \Bbb C$ and $R>0$. Let $f:B(z_0,R)\to\Bbb C$ be a complex function such that $f=u+iv$ (where $B(z_0,R)$ is the open disc centered at $z_0$ with radius $R$). If $u$ and $v$ have continuous partial derivatives then prove that
>   $$\lim\limits_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{r^2}\int\limits_{C_r}{f(z)dz}=2\pi i\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}(z_0),$$
>   where $0<r<R$ and $C_r$ is the circle $|z-z_0|=r$ oriented counter-clockwise.

I have proved it using [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem). I wanted to know if there is any proof of this without using the Green's theorem.

Comment: First, there's a typo in the statement of the problem. Yes, you can do this without Green's theorem. Say $z_0=0$. We have $u(x+iy)=a+bx+cy+E(z)$ where $E(z)/z\to0$ as $z\to0$. Similarly for $v$...

Comment: I have Fixed it!

Comment: @David C. Ullrich : Why $u$ is of that form?

Comment: It's most convenient to use the Wirtinger derivatives, $$f(z) = f(z_0) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z_0)\cdot (z-z_0) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}(z_0)\cdot (\overline{z-z_0}) + o(\lvert z-z_0\rvert).$$

Comment: Because it has continuous partials.

Answer (score 1):

Take $z = z_0 + r e^{i \theta}$ with $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, since the function has continuous derivatives we can approximate

$$
f(z) \approx f(z_0) + re^{i\theta}\frac{\partial f (z_0)}{\partial z} + re^{-i\theta} \frac{\partial f (z_0)}{\partial \bar{z}}
$$
Using $dz = i r e^{i\theta} d\theta$ in the integral above we see that only the third term in the r.h.s. above survives integration, leading to the desired result.